# Record Cpu usage per minute for particular process

Tags: system, cpu-usage, performance-testing

I want to record Cpu usage ,cpu time ,VM size in notepad per minute for any particular process(not for all.Is there any way to this,because i work as a performance/stress tester and its my duty to take the cpu performance after at particular  time and the script takes more time so it is some time  inconvenient to me take the all reading
please suggest.
thank u.

Comment: yeah but performance monitor shows the data for all process but i want only for one process like "XYZ"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use performance monitor, if the Windows is the system that you are working on. It has all kinds of log options, and will do what you need.

Performance monitor gives you the option of recording the performance data for particular process. Look under 'process'...

[image]